# Continuity of a linear map between topological vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological vector spaces. And $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear map. For any neighborhood $W$ of $0$ in Y, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $X$ such that $f(V) \subset \overline W$. Then can I conclude that $f$ is continuous? The closure of $W$ makes things much trickier than I expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any Hausdorff topolgical vector space $Y$ given a  neighborhood $W$ of $0$ there exists another neighborhood $W_1$ such that $\overline{W_1} \subset W$. Applying the hypothesis with $W_1$ in place of $W$ we get a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $X$ such that $f(V) \subset \overline {W_1}$ This gives $f(V) \subset W$.

Comment: Yes I assume tvs is always Hausdorff

Comment: I tried to prove this fact myself but it seems tricky. Could you prove this fact?

Comment: It is proved in Theorem 1.11 of Rudin's Functional Analysis.

Comment: This is true also for non-Hausdorff TVS; any TVS, being a uniform space, is automatically completely regular and hence regular.